# Sending commands to the Terminal from MacVim

Tags: vim, terminal

Is there a way to send commands between the two programs?

For example.  Lets say I have MacVim working on some code on the left, and Terminal running commands on the right (my usual set-up).  I constantly have to switch between the two programs, and this leds to lots of problems. Meta-Tab isn't really the solution here, as I am often switching to other less often run programs (Ala Chrome).

What would be awesome to see is something like running `:!rake test` from MacVim and seeing that command be executed in the Terminal.  I used to be able to do things like that when using vanilla vim, as I would just `^Z` to see the output of the command, then `fg` back into Vim.

So is there a way to do this, or know of something that would accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility would be to redirect the output to the terminal device. A Linux example (but you should be able to modify it for OS X):

```
:! rake test > /dev/pts/0
```

Comment: Yep this worked great!  Just had to use `tty` to get the terminal name, then redirect the output there using `>`.  Thank you.